# How to send a python dbus advertising (!) packet with Flags

Tags: python, dbus, bluez, nrf-connect

I am sending BLE packets via raspberry pi device. the python module which I am using is `dbus`.
As for now I am testing my packets sending with the android mobile app `nRF Connect`, and I am able to send a packet successfully and see that packet over the app.

The problem which I am facing is how to append to my packet the `Flags` values as showing in the following picture from other BLE device that was reporting a message:
[image]

See in red rect what `Flags` I am referring to

adding to add the properties in `GetAll` method as following 3 options:

1.
`self.__properties['AdvertisingFlags'] = DBusArray([DBusString('GeneralDiscoverable'), DBusString('BrEdrNotSupported')], signature='ay')`

2.
`self.__properties['AdvertisingFlags'] = DBusArray(['GeneralDiscoverable', 'BrEdrNotSupported'], signature='ay')`

3.
`self.__properties['AdvertisingFlags'] = GLibVariant('ay', 'GeneralDiscoverable')`

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved by adding
`self.__properties['Discoverable'] = dbus.Boolean(True)`

When the override method `def GetAll(self, interface):` is called.

`self.__properties` is what we `return` in the `GetAll` function.
:-)